# Visual Studio Code debugger

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

My vscode debugger no longer updates my dom or console when I hit refresh. This started after I updated my app. Please anyone know how I can fix this? Ps. I have live server extension installed.

I thought it was something to do with the debugger for chrome being deprecated in the new update, so I tried debugging with microsoft edge instead but it's  still having the same issues.

Comment: Welcome! As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)